# My electron Vuejs has a problem not rerender on data change from in promise

Tags: vuejs2

So I am using an API to get various data in an electron vue.js app and am having rerender problems in the display.  Basically my requests run fine to get data, but the vue rerender doesn't update until I reopen the page (switching routes) or some other update triggers the page to redraw.

If I only run one method when mounted, the API call works, data is displayed in my console but never on the front end.

I commented the sections in the method that are working and not working.  Why is this reactive rerender not working?

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="flex-inline">
      <div class="statusBox">
        <div class="flex-inline" :key="assetsKey">
          <div :class="{'led-green':scannerConnection, 'led-red':!scannerConnection}"></div>
          Scanner
        </div>
        <div class="statusDisplay">{{scannerStatus}}</div>
      </div>

      <div class="statusBox">
        <div class="flex-inline">
          <div :class="{'led-green':apiConnection, 'led-red':!apiConnection}"></div>
          Limble API
        </div>
        <div class="statusDisplay">{{apiStatus}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My data and method call:

```
data() { 
    return {
      APIoptions: {
        method: 'GET',
        hostname: 'api.limblecmms.com',
        port: "443",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(apikey + ':' + apisecret).toString('base64')
        }
      },
      assetsKey: 0,
      currentState:'Connecting with Asset Scanner...',
      scannerConnection: false,
      scannerStatus:'',
      apiConnection: false,
      apiStatus: ''
    }
  },
  created() {
  },
  mounted() {
    // this.listAssets()
    this.apiStatus = 'Waiting'
    this.connectAssetScanner()
  }
```

The method itself:

```
connectAssetScanner() {
      var myhost = this.$store.state.config.limble.assetScannerIP
      var myport = this.$store.state.config.limble.assetScannerPort
      const requestOptions =  {
        method: 'GET',
        host: myhost,
        port: myport,
        path: '/WS-Data/getAssetData/'
      }
      // this data rerenders just fine in the root of method
      this.scannerStatus = 'Connecting...'

      // call request and try to update display is not working
      http.request(requestOptions, res => {
        var str = ''
        res.on("data", chunk => {
          str += chunk
        })
        res.on("end", () => {
          // this prints to console just fine
          console.log(str)
          // these 2 never rerender
          this.scannerConnection = true
          this.scannerStatus = 'Connected to scanner'
          // prints to console just fine
          console.log('connected...')
        })
        res.on("error", error => {
          console.error(error)
          this.scannerStatus = 'Error connecting to scanner' 
        })
      }).end()
    }
```

Here is what I see in display and console output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd think that the problem is in scopes (this), because the code works fine without the http request and callbacks.. you can see it here.

https://codepen.io/team/Vue/pen/KKpRVpx

import Vue from 'Vue'

```
const HelloVueApp = {
data() { 
    return {
      APIoptions: {
        method: 'GET',
        hostname: 'api.limblecmms.com',
        port: "443",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(apikey + ':' + apisecret).toString('base64')
        }
      },
      assetsKey: 0,
      currentState:'Connecting with Asset Scanner...',
      scannerConnection: false,
      scannerStatus:'',
      apiConnection: false,
      apiStatus: ''
    }
  },
  created() {
  },
  mounted() {
    // this.listAssets()
    this.apiStatus = 'Waiting'
    this.connectAssetScanner()
  }, 
  methods {
  
  }
}

Vue.createApp(HelloVueApp).mount('#app')
```

Comment: Might be, but that is why I'm using arrow functions, it allows me to keep access to the 'this' scope in each response and function, does it not?  I've tried to .bind(this) with the same non-reactivity so not sure what is missing that Vue is not redrawing this.  The data clearly changes in the data object, as the console shows it updated, but the dom is not redrawing.?

Comment: mm, I've encountered  a component not rerendering once and tried forced render through a key on component and it was the thing. 

read more about it here:
https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Comment: Thanks tzknc, I've used that technique before as well but it applies to dictionaries and datasets really, since depending how you change these, they may not be reactive, I've never seen problems like I have though were individual data items (string, boolean) are not reactively rendering.  I don't believe there is any way to use a key index trick to force a single element to render anyway, since that technique works for arrays and lists.  Just don't understand what might be causing this otherwise?